# Sample queries for c# and RDLC Report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I would like to ask for any sample queries that used to retrieve multiple field from table to do maths calculation?
Another thing is, should I do the calculation in the rdlc report by using Expression, or using queries?

Comment: We don't do tutorials on broad subjects. Try your best to solve your problem. If you have problems, come here and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your first question. But I will gladly answer your second one from my point of view:

I try to do most calculations on the Database. Because thats what a database should do and complex expressions are not very good and easy to maintain.
You will have to use Expressions on top of that alle the time (in complex reports) so I prefer to do all on the Database that can be done there.

**But only as long as your SQL Queries are maintainable and fast.**

Comment: I am not using SQL Server but just a query as shown below:                    


SqlCommand custcmd  = new SqlCommand("SELECT customer.customerid, warehouse.warehouseNo, warehouse.qty_goods, warehouse.qty_slack, warehouse.std_weight, (qty_goods+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000 AS Total FROM Customer INNER JOIN warehouse WHERE customer.customerid BETWEEN" + "textbox1.text" + "AND" + "textbox2.text", myconnection);

Comment: there's a error shown "Incorrect syntax near WHERE"

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Try change it to: SqlCommand custcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT customer.customerid, warehouse.warehouseNo, warehouse.qty_goods, warehouse.qty_slack, warehouse.std_weight, (qty_goods+qty_slack)*std_weight/1000 AS Total FROM Customer INNER JOIN warehouse WHERE customer.customerid BETWEEN " + "textbox1.text" + " AND " + "textbox2.text", myconnection);

Comment: And you are using not the correct Inner Join syntax. In fact you are not joining! Try somthing like this: from customer Inner Join warehouse ***on customer.ID = warehouse.customerId***